# Strange output within loop

Tags: javascript

I have a loop like the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr);
    // rest of the code does not touch 'arr'
    ...
}
```

However, in the browser console (Chrome), I keep getting this:

```
Array[0]
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

as the output of `console.log(arr)`, which suggests that there is nothing in `arr`. But then how is it possible that the logging statement gets executed?!

Comment: at the end of your script (all the script) the array is empty?

Comment: I tried with an empty array and it doesn't enter the loop.

Comment: What's in `arr` then? Is it empty or not?

Comment: JavaScript works, if `i` is zero and `arr.length` is zero then `i < arr.length` is `false` and it will not enter your loop. So arr is not of zero length.

Comment: Where do initiate arr and with what method ?

Comment: @Andy, it is an Array object, and it should contain at least one element, and the `for` loop is inside a function which can only be reached if `arr` is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the array is empty at the end of the script, because chrome console show you the current state of the object (does change when the object itself change) **when it have been opened after script execution**. (I think it's an issue)

To reproduce this:

```
var arr = [1];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr);
}

arr.pop(); // empty the array
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47nrc/ (only for chrome)

execute it with console closed, then when you open it you could see `Array[0]`

One solution could be to log a string representation of the array:

```
console.log(arr.join());
```

See also: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316

Comment: this sounds likely. I ran the script with the console closed, and I can confirm that the loop was entered a number of times during a (long-running) execution (evidenced by the a series of output of `console.log(arr)` with the corresponding line number). Each of this output is empty.

Comment: and you pop all elements of the array as well?

Comment: eventually (after the script stops), yes, which is when I inspect the console for logging messages.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r9exf/

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log("arr = " + arr);
    // rest of the code does not touch 'arr'

}
```

compared to:

```
var arr2 = [1,2,3];

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    console.log("arr2 = " + arr2);
    // rest of the code does not touch 'arr'

}
```

Your code (assuming what you have provided is what you have), is just working fine. It does not enter the loop (see the first case and compare with second in the fiddle).

So, it must be somewhere else in your code which is logging this array.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But in Chrome console, each logging output corresponds to a line number, and I can confirm that the shown line number is exactly the one for the `console.log(arr)` inside that for loop. So it must be something else than what you've suggested.